# Jquery Clone and append

Tags: ajax

am trying to Develop invoice receipt and am using table to add input, when you click add button, the table row will append with input field, i can also delete table using remove btn, but the problem now is that i want to get product details to automatically show in input filed when i enter the barcode. the first input table row is working, but the duplicated once are not fetching the products what can i do? here is my code
which is working fine, please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
      // Denotes total number of rows
      var max = 5;
        var x = 1;
        var html = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode" placeholder="Scan barcode onkeyup="copyproduct(this.value)""></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pname" placeholder="Enter item Description"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="serialnumber" placeholder="S/N"></td><td><input type="Number" class="form-control text-center" id="qty" placeholder="1"></td><td><input type="Number" class="form-control text-center" id="price" placeholder="RM0.00" Disabled></td><td><input type="Number" class="form-control text-center" id="discount" placeholder="RM0.00"></td><td><input type="Number" class="form-control text-center" id="Total" placeholder="RM0.00" Disabled></td><td><button class="btn btn-danger" id="remove" type="button">Del</button></td></tr>'
  
      // jQuery button click event to add a row
      $('#addbtn').on('click', function () {
  if (x <= max){
      // Adding a row inside the tbody.
        $('#mytable').append(html);
      x++;
  }
        
      });
  
         $('#mytable').on('click', '#remove', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      x--;
      });
    });


var btn = document.getElementById('add_supplier');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.location.href = 'add_supplier.php';
});
```

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!-- table begin -->
                    <div class="table">
                    <table class="table table-responsive"   id="mytable">
                        <tr>
                        <th>Barcode</th>
                        <th  style="width:400px;">Item Description</th>
                        <th>Serial No</th>
                        <th style="width:20px;">Quantity</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Discount</th>
                            <th>Total Amount</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>            
        <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode"  placeholder="barcode" onkeyup="showproduct(this.value)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pname" name="pname" placeholder="Enter item Description">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="serialnumber" name="serialnumber" placeholder="S/N">
        </td>               
        <td>
            <input type="Number" class="form-control text-center" id="qty" name="qty" value="1" max="5" min="1">
        </td>       
        <td>
    <input type="Number" class="form-control text-center" id="sprice" name="sprice" placeholder="RM0.00">
  </td>
                            <td>
    <input type="Number" class="form-control text-center" id="discount" name="discount" placeholder="RM0.00">
  </td>
                                        <td>
    <input type="Number" class="form-control text-center" id="Total" placeholder="RM0.00" Disabled>
 </td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn" type="button">Add</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                </table>
                        </div>
                    <!-- End of table -->
```

```
function showproduct(str) {
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("barcode").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          document.getElementById("pname").value=myObj[0];
          document.getElementById("sprice").value=myObj[1];
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../database/invoice_function.php?barcode=" + str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, its `copyproduct(this.value)` or `showproduct(this.value)`  inside your variable `html`? Also , you have duplicate ids .Remove them and use classes.

Comment: Thank you for your support, in my original input table i have <td>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode"  placeholder="barcode" onkeyup="showproduct(this.value)">
        </td>  which the onkeyup="showproduct(this.value) fetched the first row, but when i add new table with javascript btn, and i keyin barcode, no response

Comment: when you are appending new tr your `input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode" placeholder="Scan barcode onkeyup="copyproduct(this.value)"">..` here its `copyproduct` ? isn't that should also be `showproduct` ?

Comment: thank you for your help, i have corrected the mistake but still same, when i enter barcode in row 2 it show details at row 1, not on new row here is my code

Comment: var html = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode" name="barcode" placeholder="barcode" onkeyup="showproduct(this.value)">

Comment: HI, because you have given same ids to all so only first one change value . Try using classes instead of id and pass `this` as well as parameter . Update these changes then let me know .

Comment: <td class="protable">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="barcode" placeholder="barcode" onkeyup="showproduct(this.value)">
    </td>    and js script start as function showproduct(str) {
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("protable").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } else {     unfortunately issue still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As , i already said in comments you have duplicate ids so remove all ids .Then , change `#remove` to `.remove` . Then , pass `this` as well inside your `showproduct` function . Inside this function use `el.closest("tr").querySelector("[name=yourinputname]").value` to target inputs where you need to change values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Denotes total number of rows
  var max = 5;
  var x = 1;
  //remove all ids ...
  var html = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="barcode" class="form-control"  placeholder="Scan barcode" onkeyup="showproduct(this.value ,this)"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control pname" name="pname" placeholder="Enter item Description"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control serialnumber" placeholder="S/N"></td><td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center qty" placeholder="1"></td><td><input type="number" name="sprice" class="form-control text-center price" placeholder="RM0.00" Disabled></td><td><input type="number"  name="discount" class="form-control text-center discount"  placeholder="RM0.00"></td><td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="RM0.00" Disabled></td><td><button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button">Del</button></td></tr>' //added class remove and name..for inputs..
  $('#addbtn').on('click', function() {
    if (x <= max) {

      $('#mytable').append(html);
      x++;
    }

  });
  //change here classs
  $('#mytable').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    x--;
  });

});

function showproduct(str, el) {
  /*if (str.length == 0) {
     el.closest("tr").querySelector("[name=barcode]").value="";
    return;
  same codes...*/

  el.closest("tr").querySelector("[name=pname]").value = "abcd" //myObj[0];
  el.closest("tr").querySelector("[name=sprice]").value = 1234 //myObj[1];
  /* }
    };
    //othercodes.
  }*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <table class="table table-responsive" id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>Barcode</th>
      <th style="width:400px;">Item Description</th>
      <th>Serial No</th>
      <th style="width:20px;">Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Total Amount</th>
      <th colspan="2">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- pass `this` here -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="barcode" id="barcode" placeholder="barcode" onkeyup="showproduct(this.value ,this)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pname" name="pname" placeholder="Enter item Description">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="serialnumber" name="serialnumber" placeholder="S/N">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" id="qty" name="qty" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" id="sprice" name="sprice" placeholder="RM0.00">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" id="discount" name="discount" placeholder="RM0.00">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" id="Total" placeholder="RM0.00" Disabled>
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn" type="button">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working fine now, will proceed to get the table calculation. am very grateful.

Comment: Glad was able to to help. You can set this answer accepted by clicking on tick mark.